# Seg fault while checking argv for an ampersand

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, character, argv

I have a function that checks whether argv contains ampersand at the end (shell purposes) and it gives a seg fault for seemingly no reason.. Thanks in advance

`length(char **argv)` calculates length of argv.

```
int ampersandCheck(char **argv){
    int n = length(argv);
    int i = 0;
    while(argv[n][i] != '\0'){
        if(argv[n][i] == '&' && argv[n][i+1] == '\0') return 1;
        i++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need `length` to compute what's passed to you as `argc`? How can you "compute" the length of `argv`?..

Answer (score 4):

This is because you are accessing the position `n` in `argv[n][i]`. That position does not exist. The last position you can access is `n - 1`

Comment: Indeed, but if by "length" the OP really means "the same as `argc`", then `argv[n]` *does* exist (it will just be `NULL`).